# pl-sql how to perfom a simple max(Date) function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00933

hello 
i am new to oracle db , how can i simply ask for the max date?

```
FUNCTION get_max_date_rec(
  i_value_date                  IN  vat.value_date%TYPE := app_utilities_q.server_sys_date )
RETURN vat.rec_id%TYPE
IS 
 v_date vat.value_date%TYPE; 
BEGIN

  SELECT  MAX(v.value_date)--compiler err
  INTO    v_date
  FROM    vat v 
  WHERE v.value_date < i_value_date 

  RETURN get_rec_by_date(v_date).rec_id;--compiler err

 END get_max_date_rec;
```

**EDIT**
this is the err created by the compiler
Error(76,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(81,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I want to return rec_id as writen above...

Comment: What do you want to return: the REC_ID value or the whole record?

Comment: chances are if you are creating a separate function to simply get a max value, you are making things too difficult.  Good chance this logic can/should be part of a greater SQL statement (select..group by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was
not adding

```
;
```

in the end of select

```
  SELECT  MAX(v.value_date)--compiler err
  INTO    v_date
  FROM    vat v 
  WHERE v.value_date < i_value_date ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FUNCTION get_max_date_rec(
  i_value_date  IN  vat.value_date%TYPE 
    default app_utilities_q.server_sys_date  -- assuming this is a default
  )
RETURN vat.rec_id%TYPE
IS 
 v_date vat.value_date%TYPE; 
BEGIN

  SELECT  MAX(v.value_date)--compiler err
  INTO    v_date
  FROM    vat v 
  WHERE v.value_date < i_value_date 

  RETURN v_date;

 END get_max_date_rec;
```

One risk is that if no records in `vat` exist for a date greater than `i_value_date`, the code will fail, throwing the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.  You should consider how you might wish to handle that condition - or not handle it, if that's the correct thing to do.

Comment: The original poster is missing a semicolon after `i_value_date` in the line `WHERE v.value_date < i_value_date`.  Without the full compiler error, I'm only guessing, but I suspect that is causing the compilation errors that are being reported.

Comment: You'll never get `NO_DATA_FOUND` if the query is getting an aggregate.